# ClearInterval is not defined - jQuery

Tags: javascript

To blur the keyboard on mobile devices, I use an interval with `count` on the `showPicker()` function.

```js
showPicker = function () {
  var timesRun = 0;
  var intervalblur = setInterval(function () {
    timesRun += 1;
    if (timesRun === 60) {
      clearInterval(intervalblur);
    }
    console.log('fire blur');
    editorInstance.blur();
  }, 600);
};
```

When the picker is closed, I want to clear the interval. I did on this function:

```js
hidePicker = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalblur);  
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: intervalblur is not defined

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: define intervalblur as a global variable. Replace var intervalblur with intervalblur and define intervalblur on top of function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not defined in a global scope but in `showPicker` function's scope.

You have 3 options

1. Define it globally

```js
var intervalblur;

showPicker = function () {
  var timesRun = 0;
  intervalblur = setInterval(function () {
    timesRun += 1;
    if (timesRun === 60) {
      clearInterval(intervalblur);
    }
    console.log('fire blur');
    editorInstance.blur();
  }, 600);
};

clearInterval(intervalblur);
```

2. Define it on `window`

```js
showPicker = function () {
  var timesRun = 0;
  window.intervalblur = setInterval(function () {
    timesRun += 1;
    if (timesRun === 60) {
      clearInterval(intervalblur);
    }
    console.log('fire blur');
    editorInstance.blur();
  }, 600);
};

clearInterval(intervalblur);
```

3. `showPicker` will return the intervalId

```js
showPicker = function () {
  var timesRun = 0;
  var intervalblur = setInterval(function () {
    timesRun += 1;
    if (timesRun === 60) {
      clearInterval(intervalblur);
    }
    console.log('fire blur');
    editorInstance.blur();
  }, 600);
  return intervalblur;
};

var intervalId = showPicker();

clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Personally I'd prefer option 3 because I don't like global variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me. The hidePicker and showPicker functions are defined already. I cant change this functions. Is it possible to define a interval function outside of show and hide picker and call and clear this interval in show and hide picker? Edit: Nr. 3 seems to be the right solution. I will test it. brb

Comment: If you can't change them that means the interval will remain inside showPicker, isn't? A side note, in your case I believe it's better to use `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`..

Comment: thank for you very much again. Nr. 1 was the easiest one one in my case :)

Comment: easier !== best 